# Integral involving hypergeometric functions - $\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{(ax)} U(c,d,b_1x)U(c,d,b_2x) dx$

Tags: improper-integrals, hypergeometric-function

I want to evaluate the improper integral of $\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{(ax)} U(c,d,b_1x)U(c,d,b_2x) \, dx$ where U is the confluent hypergeometric function, $d$ is a real number and  $d \in (1,2)$, $a$ and $c$ are complex numbers with both real parts $\Re(a) >0$ and $ \Re(b_1), \Re(b_2) < 0 $

Here is my attempt:

1. For starters, I tried to evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{(x)} U(1,1,x) \, dx$ (a simple case) in Wolfram, there seems to be closed form solution. The indefinite integral and plots for various values of $(a,b)$ are [here](https://sandbox.open.wolframcloud.com/app/objects/6d7735f5-9626-4e65-b990-91c01b136e87#sidebar=compute). However, I am unable to compute $\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{(x)} U(1,1,x) U(1,1,x) \, dx$ even with Wolfram.

If I can understand the step-by-step process of evaluating the integral for the simple case, I should be able to evaluate even for the general case, but unfortunately, Wolfram does not provide it.

I would be thankful if someone can help me with this integration of $$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{(ax)} U(c,d,b_1x)U(c,d,b_2x) \, dx$$

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/a/210897/118924 - A similar question. 
From this, I think we can evaluate integrals of the type $\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{(ax)} U(c,d,b_1x) \, dx$

Comment: Are the real parts of $b_{1}$ and $b_{2}$ both greater than zero as well? If so, I think your improper integral diverges for $0\le\Re{\left(a+b_{1}+b_{2}\right)}$.

Comment: @DavidH Thank you for pointing it out. Yes, $0\ge\Re (b_1), \Re(b_2)$. I am editing the original question too.

Comment: @DavidH We can consider only the case of $d \in (1,2)$, if it may help.

Comment: @DavidH Sure, I too will look into that approach. Does it help to consider that $b_{1,2}$ are just -ve real numbers, instead of considering them to be complex?

Comment: Not necessarily. Even if all parameters were positive real values, you'd still be left with complex valued functions. For example, consider that $U(\frac12,\frac32,x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$.

Comment: @DavidH, are you sure? The integral representation of the confluent hypergeometric function is $$U(c,d,z)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(c)} \int_0^\infty \color{red}{e^{-z t}} t^{c-1} (1+t)^{d-c-1} dt$$ which means we need $\Re(b_1+b_2-a)>0$ for the integral w.r.t. $x$ to converge. (The integral definition is taken from MathWorld http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConfluentHypergeometricFunctionoftheSecondKind.html)